# Angular2 gh-pages, 404 errors for files that exist

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I successfully deployed my angular2 app with these steps for a new repository

```
npm i -g angular-cli-ghpages
ng build --prod --base-href "link to project/"
angular-cli-ghpages
```

https://megdollar.github.io/angular_website/

However, now it is just saying "loading" and I have several 404 errors for files that are present in the file structure on gh-pages. Does anyone know what is going on? I am new to Angular.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.7e61ae29e06295dd0b5a.bundle.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" 
src="polyfills.e1f0c3a20d16dfbfe4af.bundle.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="vendor.ca8fcd3e0e963c2fec7b.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.a7f925a0a35424c7aab4.bundle.js">
</script>
```

those are all of the scripts it is saying its missing, but they are present in the gh-pages branch, so I can't figure out why I am getting 404 errors.

Comment: Nevermind, I got this working!

Comment: what ended up being the issue??